# I'm Trying to print my square on the middle of the console

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

Why i cant draw my square on the middle of the console?
what do i need to change? 
it jut prints the first line, please help, thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"


 using namespace System;
 using namespace std;


 void DibujaCuadrado()
{
 for (int f=1;f<=5;f++)
   {
    for (int c=1; c<=5;c++)
    {
        cout << "O";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
Console::SetWindowSize(80, 40);
Console::SetCursorPosition(40, 20);
DibujaCuadrado();

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using both standard C++ console output as well as CLR System::Console namespace cursor positioning. The `std::endl` will reset the cursor position to the left hand side. You probably want to reset the cursor position after each f-`for` loop maybe using `Console::CursorLeft = 40;`.